# onActivityResult in Fragment can't access UI elements

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a button in Fragment when I press it I open a new activity for result but When I return back to my fragment I found all UI element = null

Please find the code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, "3030");
            }
    });
```

when choose a value from activity I should back to fragment and set data to textview in the activity.

```
    Intent intent = Activity.this.getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("categoryId", id);
    intent.putExtra("categoryName", name);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

and I have put that in the activity that contains the fragment

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 3030 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Fragment fragment = mTabFragments.get(MyFragment.class.getName());

            if (fragment != null) {

                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

and in fragment

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 3030 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            int categoryId = data.getIntExtra("categoryId", 0);
            String categoryName = data.getStringExtra("categoryName");
            mChooseCategoryTextView.setText(categoryName);
        }
    }
```

the problem now that mChooseCategoryTextView is null

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: What `Fragment fragment = mTabFragments.get(MyFragment.class.getName());` line does?

Comment: it get the current selected fragment that shown in tab host

Comment: Are you sure your `mTabFragments.get` call is returning the existing Fragment and not creating a new one?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Can anyone give an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

To get result in fragment

```
startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
```

not

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter. Their Activity implementation passes down the result to the fragment anyways.

Comment: the result is already connected and I can get the values of categoryId and categoryName, the problem is setting the value in TextView that already found in the fragment.

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed the part where he calls Fragment on his own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question how you initialise this view?
Since your lunching another activity so your whole fragment my be reconstruct or only onViewCreated recalled again.

So my guess is that you don't reinitialize or override mChooseCategoryTextView reference in one of fragment callbacks.

Try to add more logs and check what's happening for this reference

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in the line
`Fragment fragment = mTabFragments.get(MyFragment.class.getName());`
I assume `mTabFragments` in an adapter of some sort? I'd have to look at it's code to be sure, but it sounds like it's not returning the right fragment. Make sure that the reference it's returning is the same as the fragment that is being shown on screen.

Comment: I have debug the code many times, and it is already call the right fragment, and call onActivityResult in the right fragment, but found all the UI in it = null